# JSch for SSH freezes in debug mode

Tags: java, eclipse, ssh, jsch

I have function to retrieve output of command ran on a server over ssh:

```
public static List<String> executeCmd(Session session, String cmd) throws IOException, JSchException{
        System.out.println("Executing : "+cmd);
        //String response = null;
        List<String> l = new ArrayList<>();

        ChannelExec ch= (ChannelExec)session.openChannel("exec");
         if(ch == null)
             throw new JSchException("Unable to create channel");

        ch.setInputStream(null);
        ch.setErrStream(System.err);
        ch.setCommand(cmd);
        ch.connect();
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(ch.getInputStream()));
        String line;
        while((line = in.readLine())!= null){
            System.out.println(line);
            l.add(line);
        }
        ch.disconnect();

        return l;
    }
```

> If I run this program in debug mode, it will freeze on in.readLine()
>   call.

I am using JSCh 1.51 in eclipse.

File I am trying to tail is on a server - a log file.

'`tail -f`' on putty for the file poses no problem.

Why does this program freeze in debug mode?

Comment: Your exception stacktrace doesn't seem to have any relationship to the code that you posted. Could you edit your question to include the entire exception message and stacktrace?

Comment: @Kenster you are right, that log I posted had nothing to do with the problem, it was actually rectriving and displaying the error from the log it was tailing, I am sorry for the wrong information, I am editing the question.